# Getting error "Error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out : ``" when trying to build on my mac but in ubuntu everything looks good

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

When it was trying to build on my Mac, the following issue occurred "Error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out:"

When I was building the Django project on my Mac.

The following issue is occurring.

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d --build
Password:
WARN[0000] The "hl0" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "hl0" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "hl0" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "hl0" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
2023/05/21 14:09:08 must use ASL logging (which requires CGO) if running as root
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠋ db Pulling                                                              0.0s
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: ``
```

**My docker-compose :**

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.0-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${SQL_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${SQL_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${SQL_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - rbn_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - rbn
  web:
    build: ./
#    command: gunicorn monsite.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    ports:
      - "9005:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - rbn
volumes:
  rbn_db:

networks:
  rbn:
    driver: bridge
```

**.env file :**

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY=(gq!il9r&&a49rweb47qxwwogjsqeq2$hl0+6s6nx8dx^3
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost;127.0.0.1
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=rbn
SQL_USER=rbn_user
SQL_PASSWORD=gjjhgfjgfdgfgdsfsf
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
DJANGO_DEBUG=True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try editing `~/.docker/config.json` and replacing `"credsStore": "desktop"` with `"credsStore": "osxkeychain"`.

Comment: This right here! This one fixed my problem after trying 10 different approaches all ending with the same error. Even tried reinstalling docker, deleting its caches and everything it didn't work, but changing the credsStore to osxkeychain was the solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I went through the same hell you described.